# How to change the format of POJOs generated from JSON Schema?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm having issues in generating the correct POJOs required for the downstream call. An enum 'abc' is generating as 'ABC'. However, enum "UVwxYZ" is generating as UV_WX_YZ, while my requirement is it be generated as "UVWXYZ". I'm currently using JCodeModel to generate the POJOs. I cannot change the enum "UVwxYZ" to a "uvwxyz" or "UVWXYZ" as the schema already has dependencies.

This is the schema snippet:

```
{
    "repositoryType": {
        "type": "string",
        "enum": [
            "ABC",
            "UVwxYZ"
        ]
    }
}
```

This, when the POJO is generated, is showing as :

```
ABC("ABC"),
UV_WX_YZ("UVwxYz");
```

Comment: can you add some code to your question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo can add `@JsonValue` on the getter of your field:

```java
enum SOEnum {
 ABC("ABC"),
 UV_WX_YZ("UVwxYz");

 private final String value;

 @JsonValue
 public String getValue() {
   return value;
 }
}
```

If the enum is used in serialization with jackson the result will be `"ABC", "UVwxYz"`.

You can play with the getter to transform the result like adding `toUpperCase()` to the `value`